# NA's for blanks in web scraping

Tags: r, node.js, web-scraping, rvest

I want to scrape the below mentioned page, but there are some blanks in "*.trans-section*" node. '.trans-section' node is capturing '*title*' as well as '*description*'. In some table title will be there, but description is missing. ***I want the data to be filled with NA's when the description is blank***. Since the node is same for both I am not getting any blank lines. Please help on this.

Weblink: https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/result.jsf?currentNavigationRow=5&prevCurrentNavigationRow=2&query=FP:(Gaming)&office=&sortOption=Pub%20Date%20Desc&prevFilter=&maxRec=39316&viewOption=All&listLengthOption=200

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(XML)


FinalD <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:10) {
rm(Data)

## Creating web page  
Webpage <- paste0('https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/result.jsf?currentNavigationRow=',i,'&prevCurrentNavigationRow=1&query=&office=&sortOption=Pub%20Date%20Desc&prevFilter=&maxRec=64653917&viewOption=All&listLengthOption=100')
Webpage <- read_html(Webpage)

#Getting Nodes
Node_Intclass <- html_nodes(Webpage,'.trans-section')
Intclass <- data.frame(html_text(Node_Intclass))
Intclass$sequence <- seq(1:2)

Node_Others <- html_nodes(Webpage,'.notranslate')
Others <- data.frame(html_text(Node_Others))
Others$sequence <- seq(1:9)

####Others
Data <- data.frame(subset(Others$html_text.Node_Others.,Others$sequence == 1))
Data$ID <- subset(Others$html_text.Node_Others.,Others$sequence == 2)
Data$Country <- subset(Others$html_text.Node_Others.,Others$sequence == 3)
Data$PubDate <- subset(Others$html_text.Node_Others.,Others$sequence == 4)
Data$IntClass <- subset(Others$html_text.Node_Others.,Others$sequence == 5)
Data$ApplINo <- subset(Others$html_text.Node_Others.,Others$sequence == 7)
Data$Applicant <- subset(Others$html_text.Node_Others.,Others$sequence == 8)
Data$Inventor <- subset(Others$html_text.Node_Others.,Others$sequence == 9)

###Content
ifelse ((nrow(Intclass) == 200),
  ((Data$Title <- subset(Intclass$html_text.Node_Intclass.,Intclass$sequence == 1))&
  (Data$Content <- subset(Intclass$html_text.Node_Intclass.,Intclass$sequence == 2))),
((Data$Title <- 0 ) & (Data$Content = 0)))

#Final Data
FinalD <- rbind(FinalD,Data)
}

write.csv(FinalD,'FinalD.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not an expert of Web Scraping ( I have just tried a few times) but I have realized that it is a tiresome procedure with a lot of trials and errors.

Maybe you can use the RSelenium package as the page is dynamically generated.For me it works but it creates a kind of messy output ,maybe it is better though.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
tables1  <-  list()
for (i in 1:10) { # i <- 1; i
  ## Creating web page  
  url <- paste0('https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/result.jsf?currentNavigationRow=',i,'&prevCurrentNavigationRow=1&query=&office=&sortOption=Pub%20Date%20Desc&prevFilter=&maxRec=64653917&viewOption=All&listLengthOption=100')
  rD <- rsDriver( browser="chrome")
  remDr <- rD$client

  remDr$navigate(url)
  page <- remDr$getPageSource()

  remDr$close() 

  table <- page[[1]] %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(xpath='//table[@id="resultTable"]') %>% # specify table as there is a div with same id
    html_table(fill = T)

  table <- table[[1]]

  tables1[[url]] <- table %>% as.data.table()
  rm(rD)
  gc()}
```

I would also suggest you to create the list of pages that you want to read, outside the loop, and create an index so as if the connection fails you continue from the page you were left.

In addition, if the connection fails, run the

```
 rm(rD)
  gc()
```

lines to avoid an error that says that the port is already in use.

I hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try this and let you know the result.

Answer (score 0):

(Not tested)

Can you try to add the option:

```
read_html(Webpage, options =  c("NOBLANKS"))
```

Comment: "not tested" == this is a comment vs an answer

Comment: @hrbrmstr That is true, but I need 50 reputation to comment... In addition, I tested the script, but I can not spot the blanks in the page...

Comment: @GeorgeSotiropoulos, Thanks but above syntax is not working.

Comment: @GeorgeSotiropoulos, I am trying to scrape the entire table,due to missing I am not able to match Intclass with data. Where I am making a mistake?